# How to always listen for amazon sqs in python django rest framework

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-sqs, django-celery

I am new to python django rest framework and I need to listen amazon sqs continuously in framwwork.
where I can run while loop infinitely or Can I use Celery[sqs] for this purpose? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/jegesh/python-sqs-listener

Answer (score -1):

In short, Celery is preferable. 
But, there are tradeoffs in each approach. I will list out the pros / cons of each method.

***Celery :***

**Pros :**

- celery : is a background process which runs as worker by listening to some messaging broker( celery has a support to configure rabbitmq / redis / sqs as the message broker)
- you don't need to set-up the boiler plate code to listen to a queue
- Easily manageable and extensible for future needs
- Once you understand the things deeply, it's just a matter of configuration. Django-celery has an excellent documentation

**Cons :**

- It's hardly possible to make the things work with cent percent accuracy unless you have deep understanding
- Celery has only limited support for sqs. for eg : celery events are not supported by using sqs as a message broker.

***Own worker:***

**Pros :**

- You might be having more control over what needs to happen.
- you will get a change to build a base and keep adding the features as and when needed.

**Cons** : [The most interesting one's are here]

- In industry, it's not hard to build something which is working in
  your local box functionally. It's more about : How do we scale? How
  do we handle fail overs? How to make our application fault tolerant?
  How do we handle concurrency? How do we handle duplicates (in this
  case)? and much more..
- Good developers code, better developers re-use. So, writing boiler plate code when a framework exists is something should be avoided.